# Página 404 - Imagem de erro

Tags: novo-recurso

Se for em uma [página não encontrada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/404) do SOPT verá esta imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E no [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/404) existe esta imagem que é mais interessante:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

PS: se possível acho que deveríamos utilizar a [versão atualizada](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/27846) do mesmo.

Comment: Pessoalmente prefiro o 404

Comment: @JorgeB. não gosto do 404 por ser o padrão da rede e o mesmo usado no MSE. Parece-me falta de personalidade manter o padrão.